# Problems With Particle Rotation

Tags: modeling, modifiers, particles, procedural, particle-nodes

I am trying to create pipes and AC Units on a building, I am trying to use a particle system to generate new buildings that look different. Unfortunately, the AC Units are all facing random directions. I am following a video to successfully do this here is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9CvFVJYaTU&t=34s
And here is an image:[image][image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post.  Can you include some screenshots of the settings for the particle system?

Comment: Sure thing, post should be updated